# How can I run ajax code without web server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am running ajax without a server on my system, I have created one index.html with this.

**JavaScript function:**

```
function do_the_click(url)
{
alert('inside this method do_the_click');
    $.ajax({
                         async: false,
                         url : url, 
                         contentType: "text/html",
                         type : "GET",
                         dataType : "text/html",                
                         success: function(data){
                         alert('data');
           }});
}
```

My HTML body content is:

```
<a href="Java Collections.html" class="button" id="javacollections" onclick="do_the_click('this.href');"/>Java Collections</a>
```

I'm able to get the this message in alert window *inside this method `do_the_click`* but am not able to get the data in alert window, and so not able to get the page Java Collections.html in the index.html,

I have searched very much on Google re. how to load the data locally without using server in `jquery.ajax` but I didn't find any good solution, so I think that its good for others as well if it resides on Stack overflow.

Comment: @MikeW I would not agree to this. Making AJAX request without server is possible. I have done it several times. The browser makes the HTTP request on your behalf.

Comment: I think you meant to use `do_the_click(this.href)` without the single quotes. The request may still fail because there is a space in the filename though, you probably want to get rid of the space.

Comment: As long as there is no "cross domain ajax request" I don't see any reason why they can't make AJAX requests from a stand alone html page not running on any server. I have done it numerous times when developing HTML 5 apps for mobile. The app has to be compiled in PhoneGap so all AJAX requests are made as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I m able to run the ajax without webserver the problem was with my code the code written below that i had run on my filesystem u can use that as well.

```
      function do_the_click(brl)
      {
          alert('inside this method do_the_click');
          alert(brl);
          var request  =     $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    url: brl, 
                    contentType: "text/html",
                    type : "GET",
                    dataType : "html",                
                });

                request.done(function( msg ) {
                          alert(msg);
                          $( "#contentarea" ).load( msg, function() {
                                    alert( "Load was performed." );
                          });
                });

                request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                          alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                });

      }
```

Java Collections

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do such thing. if you dont have a server you cannot send ajax it will be a cross browser issue. as the others says ajax will not work with `file://` protocol you need a server to make an `http://` call that ajax supports.

Answer (score 3):

When you are making AJAX requests using stand alone html files, the HTTP request to the url is made by the browser. All you need to make sure is that you have included JQuery. Here is what you have to do.

**Include Jquery:**

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

The JQuery here resides in the js folder. This is included in the stand alone html file. Now to make the AJAX request use the following code.

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url:  url, 

          success: function(data){
              console.log(data);
          },
          async:false
      });
```

Comment: I have did that, I have already included jquery-1.10.2.min.js this might be a issue with file system, ihave to chk that

Comment: Put Jquery inside js folder and reference from there. Don't put Jquery file in the same folder.

Comment: I m using this url for http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js, I have used it many times

Comment: I was using Jquery locally. Although its a very good idea to use Jquery from cdn, but for the sake of proving a point, you can use JQuery locally. My point is that there is absolutely no problem making AJAX calls from stand alone code without server.

Comment: ya, I am not able to get the data using file system

Comment: Did you include JQuery locally? Also see that what type of data the server is returning. In your AJAX configurations you have specified that you expect "text/html". So you might want to check that out as well.

Comment: Then Kindly +1 my answer if I was able to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

AJAX creates an HTTP request that must be responded to by a server. If you don't have a server you can't use an AJAX request. You can run a server on your computer, but this is not the same as getting a file from the local filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this. If you don't have a server, you will violate the browser's cross-domain policy, as you won't have a domain!

AJAX won't work via the filesystem, you need a server.

Answer (score 0):

This is an older thread but a browser doesn't need to run on a common OS like OSX/Windows/etc .. many people today are making their own browsers from WPE/Wayland or QT5Webkit where same origin policies don't apply.

Answer (score 0):

Now in current scenario it depends upon where your server at. If the server is some place else, it will require CORS (cross origin request). So using file:// with CORS works perfectly.

I came to this question because I was searching for the reason, why I am able to make ajax request without using a web server. Got the answer Thanks!